# Get a part of the name by listing

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have following files in a directory called "downloads" how can i get a part of the name(shared,fmw,local) from the file name. The string comes after "1000_server003_" may not have a fixed length but "1000_server003_" remain fixed every time.

```
1000_server003_shared.tar.gz.part-aa
1000_server003_shared.tar.gz.part-ab
1000_server003_shared.tar.gz.part-ac
1000_server003_shared.tar.gz.part-ad
1000_server003_fmw.tar.gz.part-aa
1000_server003_fmw.tar.gz.part-ab
1000_server003_fmw.tar.gz.part-ac
1000_server003_local.tar.gz.part-aa
1000_server003_local.tar.gz.part-ab
```

result should be as follows

```
shared
fmw
local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_` and `.` as delimiters to extract the required fields.

`awk -F[_.] '{print $3}' file_name`

Output:

```
shared
shared
shared
shared
fmw
fmw
fmw
local
local
```

if you want the distinct names only, just pipe it to `sort`:

```
awk -F[_.] '{print $3}' file_name |sort -u
```

Output:

```
fmw
local
shared
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
/tmp> ls -1 1000_server0*
1000_server003_fmw.tar.gz.part-aa
1000_server003_fmw.tar.gz.part-ab
1000_server003_fmw.tar.gz.part-ac
1000_server003_local.tar.gz.part-aa
1000_server003_local.tar.gz.part-ab
1000_server003_shared.tar.gz.part-aa
1000_server003_shared.tar.gz.part-ab
1000_server003_shared.tar.gz.part-ac
1000_server003_shared.tar.gz.part-ad
/tmp> perl -e ' print map {(split(/[_.]/))[2],"\n" } @ARGV ' 1000_server0*
fmw
fmw
fmw
local
local
shared
shared
shared
shared
```

If you need just the unique ones

```
/tmp> perl -le ' $kv{(split(/[_.]/))[2]}++ for(@ARGV); print foreach(keys %kv) ' 1000_server0*
shared
fmw
local
/tmp>
```